# Nvidia 2070 super drivers not working with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

My system config:

Ubuntu 18.04

Graphic card - Nvidia RTX 2070 super(Gigabyte)

CPU - AMD Ryzen

Nvidia Driver version - 435

I tried to install drivers from both PPA and Nvidia website.
Typing `nvidia-smi` returns

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and try again.